# Local variable referenced before assignment (but is it a bug?)

Tags: python, function, variables, debugging, global

I'm trying to write an encryption function which works on bits, summing them up to get a new combination a bits, so i have this code:

```
a=list("100010")
b=list("1100011")
n=[]
tmp=b[0]

for z in a:
    if int(z)==1:
        for y in b:
            if int(tmp)==1:
                tmp=0
            else:
                tmp=1
    else:
        for y in b:
            if int(y)==1:
                tmp=1
            else:
                tmp=0
    n.append(tmp)
    del tmp
print(n)
```

now python returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vitto\OneDrive\Desktop\python\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\vitto\OneDrive\Desktop\python\test.py", line 23, in main
    summing(temp)
  File "C:\Users\vitto\OneDrive\Desktop\python\test.py", line 8, in summing
    if int(tmp)==1:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tmp' referenced before assignment
```

i tried using globals as a user from another page of stack overflow wrote, i now globals shouldn't be used to refer about a variable outside a function, anyway this user suggested to do like this:

```
a=list("100010")
b=list("1100011")
n=[]
tmp=b[0]
def test():
    global tmp
    for z in a:
        if int(z)==1:
            for y in b:
                if int(tmp)==1:
                    tmp=0
                else:
                    tmp=1
        else:
            for y in b:
                if int(y)==1:
                    tmp=1
                else:
                    tmp=0
        n.append(tmp)
        del tmp
test()
```

same error as before, so i tried:

```
a=list("100010")
b=list("1100011")
n=[]
tmp=b[0]
def test(tmp):
    for z in a:
        if int(z)==1:
            for y in b:
                if int(tmp)==1:
                    tmp=0
                else:
                    tmp=1
        else:
            for y in b:
                if int(tmp)==1:
                    tmp=1
                else:
                    tmp=0
        n.append(tmp)
        del tmp
tmp=b[0]
test(tmp)
```

i'm probably doing something wrong here but i really cannot figure out what. I know i've inserted a lot of code, but it's to avoid receiving answers already on the site.

Answer (score 1):

you are deleting `tmp` after the first iteration rather than after the loop. If you want to delete after all your iterations are over, this work:

```
a=list("100010")
b=list("1100011")
n=[]
tmp=b[0]

for z in a:
    if int(z)==1:
        for y in b:
            if int(tmp)==1:
                tmp=0
            else:
                tmp=1
    else:
        for y in b:
            if int(y)==1:
                tmp=1
            else:
                tmp=0
    n.append(tmp)
del tmp
print(n)
```

it gives `[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]` However I am not sure you *need* to delete, you can just let the garbage collector do its job and not delete the variable.

Comment: thank you very much for the fast answer, anyway, tmp is not a gabage collector, it has to contain only one integer, which should be each the first and the second addend of the sum.

Comment: what I meant is that the python garbage collector will delete the data of tmp automatically without you needing to explicitly use `del`